# mock http server in phpunit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, fuelphp

i write a test for my controller,it need $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI],how can i mock this and make it run
my controller is

```
public function action_index()
{
  $presenter = Presenter::forge('www/php');
  $this->template->content = $presenter;
}
```

my test is

```
public function test_action_index()
{
  $response = Request::forge('www/php')
    ->set_method('GET')
    ->execute()
    ->response();
  $this->assertContains(' List', $response->body->__toString());
  Cli::write(__METHOD__ . "   √ \n", 'green');
}
```

Comment: i think testing controllers its not a business of PhpUnit. I d better use some E2E testing for that

Answer (score 0):

1. You can set this global yourself, but it's very ugly.
2. You can set it via SetEnv (see this blog :http://westsworld.dk/blog/2011/01/handle-different-environments-with-php/)
3. But, it's better to change your line with $_SERVER['*']

**Why?**

The description of an unit test is:

a small **isolated** test of your method

Your code will depend on globals! No! Use your request object for example to get the uri.